# Is the quotient of a normal subgroup necessarily normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $N,M$ be normal subgroups of $G$.

Is it necessarily true that $M/N$ is normal in $G/N$?

The third isomorphism says the converse to be true, namely that if a group in $G/N$ is normal, then it is of the form $M/N$ for some normal subgroup $M$ of $G$.

---

My attempt at proving this as true:

- $G/N$ consists of cosets of $N$. i.e. a group element looks like $gN$
  for $g \in G$.
- $M/N$ consists of cosets of $N$. i.e. a group element looks like $mN$
  for $m \in M$.
- $M/N$ as a set may be expressed as $\{mN : m \in M\}$
- If we conjugate everything in $M/N$ by something in $G/N$ we get $\{gN \cdot mN : m \in M\} = \{g^{-1}mgN : m \in M\} = \{mN : m \in M\}$

Is this correct? I feel it is, but I'm suspicious due to the fact that this isn't listed in the isomorphism theorems on Wikipedia...

Comment: $M/N$ may not be defined.

Comment: @KennyLau - I think you've hit the heart of the problem, but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around it. Could you please explain? What stops us from forming that quotient structure, viewed as cosets acting upon one another?

Comment: $M/N$ is always defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $N$ and $M$ are normal subgroups of $G$.  If $N \subseteq M$, it's easy to see that $M/N$ is a normal subgroup of $G/N$.  But you are not assuming $N \subseteq M$, so this is just a special case.

Do not assume that $N \subseteq M$.  Let $H = NM = \{ nm : n \in N, m \in M \}$.  Note that $H = MN$.  Since $N$ and $M$ are both normal subgroups of $G$, so is $H$.

The set $M/N$ of cosets $mN : m \in M$ is a subgroup of $G/N$.  It is equal to $H/N$, which is normal in $G/N$ by the special case mentioned above.  So $M/N$ is normal in $G/N$ even if $N \not\subseteq M$.

**Another way**: This is basically what you did  in your post, I'm just going to state it in a different way.  If $\pi: G \rightarrow G'$ is a surjective group homomorphism, and $M$ is normal in $G$, then $\pi(M)$ is a normal subgroup of $G'$.  Again pretty much the same as your case: if $N = \textrm{Ker}(\pi)$, then you can identify $G'$ with $G/N$ via the first isomorphism theorem, under which $\pi(M)$ gets identified with $M/N$.

Comment: Alright well I have one question: this seems like an important fact which can be used in many cases, so why isn't it part of the isomorphism theorems? (Why do they stipulate that $N \subseteq M$?)

Comment: They might as well.  If $N$ is normal in $G$, then $M \mapsto M/N$ is an order preserving bijection between subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ and subgroups of $G/N$, and normal subgroups correspond to normal subgroups.  If $M$ does not contain $N$, then the image $M/N$ of $M$ is still a subgroup of $G/N$.  The unique subgroup of $G$ containing $N$ to which it corresponds is the group $MN$ generated by $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Thank you, that last comment is very helpful.

Comment: They stipulate $N \subset M$ to preserve the bijection.

Comment: Isn't $M/N$ only defined when $N$ is a normal subgroup of $M$? This seems like $MN/N$.

Comment: They are the same.  By $M/N$ I mean the image of $M$ under the canonical homomorphism $G \rightarrow G/N$.  The notation makes sense: $$M/N = \{ mN : m \in M \}$$

Comment: @D_S do you have a reference for that definition being valid even when $N$ is not a subgroup of $M$? If you do that, you would lose the exactness of $0 \longrightarrow N \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow M/N \longrightarrow 0$.

Comment: What is not valid about the definition?  It has nothing to do with the exact sequence you wrote (which is not well defined since there is no inclusion $N \rightarrow M$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $gN \in G/N$ and $hN \in M/N$.

In particular, $g \in G$ and $h \in M$.

So, $ghg^{-1} \in M$.

Then, $(gN)(hN)(gN)^{-1} = (ghg^{-1})N \in M/N$.

Therefore, $M/N$ is normal in $G/N$.

---

The [third isomorphism theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Third_Isomorphism_Theorem/Groups) states that for $N \le M \le G$ with $N$ and $M$ being normal subgroups of $G$, then:

1. $M/N$ is normal in $G/N$.
2. $(G/N)/(M/N) \cong G/M$

So in fact this is part of the third isomorphism theorem itself, not its converse.

Comment: But this has the requirement $N \leq M$. Also, I updated by question and it looks like I have the same working as you :)